# Form not working as it should in WordPress, but in a normal HTML site it does

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I am in need of help.

I have a website, which has a form to fill out (simple form, that calls a PHP function and some other JQuery libraries). It is made in an ordinary HTML file, and works well on my servers.

Now I have a new site made in WordPress. The site works great and everything, but the form does not. I do not have so much experience with WordPress to tell what is wrong. It does show, but it does not function properly. Can somebody please check it out? The biggest problem is the button, where you choose how to »pay«. It does actually redirect you, but it should happen twice, but it does not…

This is the site: http://www.zivimo.zdravo-zivljenje.org/naravno/

I just copied the code into the past of the site and of course I uploaded the required files to the server, so that it has all the files and functions that it needs.

This is my code:
http://pastie.org/10798862

Comment: Please paste your code here.

Comment: Is the PHP folder / file that your form is looking for in the root directory? I'm willing to bet once you put it in WordPress it can't locate the file properly - ensure you can access the file.

Comment: I put it inside of the root of the directory. Is there any way of checking if it does not find it? But i am quite certain, it does find it. The problem is somewhere else!

Comment: Figure out a way to test if you can access the file. Either by `include()` or `require()` or something of the sort to ensure your form can access the file. Maybe [enable debugging](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress#WP_DEBUG) though I'm not sure it monitor expectedly in this scenario.

Comment: Did that. No errors of such

Comment: Look in your browser's javascript error console.

Comment: Jp, no errors. Maybe PHP problems?

Comment: no errors? `jquery.validate.min.js` is returning 404 and there are two syntax errors.

Comment: What does that mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally found the solution to the problem. It was in the validate.js function. I corrected the error by calling the outside functions of validate.js and jquerry:

```
script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"

script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.min.js"
```